# How to keep nesting SQL statements?

Tags: oracle

I have the following relational model (primary keys between asterisks, and foreign keys preceded with a hash sign):

```
SALLE ( *nSALLE* , nameSALLE)
POSTE ( *nPOSTE* , #nSALLE)
LOGICIEL ( *nLOG* , purchaseDate)
INSTALLER ( #nPOSTE , #nLOG,...)
```

The question is to attribute a system date to the purchaseDate of `LOGICIEL` that are purchased before 2018 and that are installed in `SALLE` with the name "SALLE3"

I know that the idea is to keep joining tables, but I'm confused about how to nest the statements.

```sql
SQL> UPDATE LOGICIEL
  2  SET purchaseDate= GETDATE()
  3  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM purchaseDate) < 2018
  4  AND EXISTS(
  5  SELECT * FROM SALLE S
  6  INNER JOIN POSTE P ON S.nSALLE=P.nSALLE
  7  WHERE ...
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Just join installer, poste and salle on their keys. You can use `EXISTS` or `IN` for this.

```
UPDATE logiciel
SET purchaseDate = SYSDATE
WHERE purchaseDate < DATE '2018-01-01'
AND nlog IN
(
  SELECT i.nlog
  FROM installer i
  JOIN poste p ON p.nposte = i.nposte
  JOIN salle s ON s.nsalle = p.nsalle
  WHERE s.namesalle = 'SALLE3'
);
```

The same is possible with a chain of `EXISTS` or `IN`:

```
AND nlog IN
(
  SELECT i.nlog
  FROM installer i
  WHERE i.nposte IN
  (
    SELECT p.nposte 
    FROM poste p
    WHERE p.nsalle =
    (
      SELECT s.nsalle 
      FROM salle s
      WHERE s.namesalle = 'SALLE3'
    )
  )
);
```

In the end this is a matter of personal preference.